# PHP echo data from nested array (foreach loop)

Tags: php, arrays, nested, echo

I am having problems echoing array data from a nested array, my array (for a single order) looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [buyer_name] => Mr Smith
    [buyer_phone] => 01234 567890
    [buyer_email] => mygreatemail@fakeemail.com
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 3
                    [item_title] => title 1
                    [custom_label] => JD3433
                    [item_variation] => Variation detail for title 1
                    [price] => £8.00
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [item_title] => title 2
                    [custom_label] => JD5544
                    [item_variation] => Variation detail for title 2
                    [price] => £7.00
                )

        )

)
```

Generated from this code...

```
 function readCSV($csvFile)
    {
        $output = [];
        $fileHandle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        $header = fgetcsv($fileHandle);
        while (!feof($fileHandle)) {
            $fileRow = fgetcsv($fileHandle, 1024);
            $orderId = $fileRow[0];
            // skip this row if it's empty (the first field contains no id)
            if (empty($orderId)) {
                continue;
            }
            /*
              $fileRow[3] is "Buyer name", the first field that's present in one type of row
              (the one containing common properties of the order). By checking if it's empty,
              we identify the contents of the row - not empty means order row with common
              properties, empty means item row with specific item properties.
             */
            if (!empty($fileRow[3])) {
                // no need to repeat the id inside the array - it's already stored in the key
                $output[$orderId] = [
                    'sales_record' => $fileRow[0],
                    'order_number' => $fileRow[1],
                    'buyer_username' => $fileRow[2],
                    'buyer_name' => $fileRow[3],
                    // here you can continue explicitly adding any property you need
                ];
            } else {
                // add a new item entry
                $output[$orderId]['items'][] = [
                    'item_number' => $fileRow[20],
                    'item_title' => $fileRow[21],
                    'quantity' => $fileRow[24],
                    'price' => $fileRow[25],
                    // here you can continue explicitly adding any property you need
                ];
            }
        }
        fclose($fileHandle);

        return $output;
    }
```

I can echo individual main array data without issue using..

```
foreach($csv as $order) {
echo "Sales Record: "; echo $order[sales_record]; 
}
```

But having problems trying to echo nested array data.

I have read many similar questions on here and tried..

```
foreach($csv[$orderId]['items'] as $orderitems) {
echo $orderitems; echo "<br>";

}
```

with no luck, what am I doing wrong, please?

EDIT TO ADD...

If I can't echo the array in that way then this would result in me using lots of "if" statements (there could be 100+ items in an order) and the below is just for an example for "title", I'd have to repeat several hundred times for each item in the nested array, there must be a better way to achieve this??

```
    if ($order[items][0][item_title] != "") { echo $order[items][0][item_title]; echo "<br>"; } else {}
    if ($order[items][1][item_title] != "") { echo $order[items][1][item_title]; echo "<br>"; } else {}
    if ($order[items][2][item_title] != "") { echo $order[items][2][item_title]; echo "<br>"; } else {}

//and so on
```

Comment: you cant `echo` an Array. if you wish, use `var_dump` or `print_r`. I can't find the key sales_record in your Array description; array-keys must be quoted `$order['Sales_record'];`. possible you use and old php-construct (unknown constant as string) that will be removed in future Releases...

Comment: @chriss thanks for that info, The code I'm using is from here (accepted answer) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086934/php-array-merging-ignore-certain-duplicated-keys-and-let-them-be-included-in-th
which suggests I could use foreach($orders[$orderId]['items'] as $item) please check that out and also check my edit in this question too if you'd be so kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, array-keys must be in Quotation marks:

- no: `$order[items][0][item_title]`
- yes: `$order['items'][0]['item_title']`

Normally your PHP version throws a warning:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant item_title - assumed 'item_title' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

You can iterate over the array:

```
foreach($order['items'] as $item) {
  echo $item['item_title']."<br/>";
}
```

If you have a nested array (array of orders and each order has an array of items) you can nest the foreach.

```
$orders = readCSV('filename.csv');

foreach ($orders as $orderId=>$order) {    
  foreach($order['items'] as $item) {
    if (!empty($item['item_title'])) echo $item['item_title']."<br/>";
  }
}
```

`.` concat two strings. You don't Need two echo-commands.

Pay attention to the wording, that makes the code more readable.

```
foreach (<plural> as <singular>)
```